# Querying MySQL InnoDB to find if the Record is in its Buffer Pool

Tags: mysql, caching, buffer, innodb

For us, it is very important to get high response time for our website php script which queries a large database. It is essentially getting user information for the user who visited the page. There may be millions of users in the db.

We would like to not bother using the user data at all if the record is not already in the InnoDB Buffer Pool of the MySQL database, and use information only if present in the above cache.

Is there a way to directly ask Mysql/InnoDB whether the record is in cache?

Answer (score 0):

Heisenberg says it would be inefficient.  (OK, maybe that is a bad paraphrase.)

You do not have millions of users *at the same time*, the Ethernet cables would melt.

What do you want to do?  Say "your data is not in the cache, so you can't access your account"?  I doubt it.

The basic row for a million users might take 0.1GB.  How tiny is your machine?

OK, I'll get serious.

No, there is no way to ask if a row is cached in the buffer_pool.

I contend that there is no need to ask.  Think about what it means to be "cached" (in a LRU mechanism).  A user who returns before his record is bumped out of cache will find it in memory; the other users will incur a few *milliseconds* extra delay to get their data.  And this assumes you don't have room to cache the entire 0.1GB all the time (once the buffer_pool is warmed up).

As an analogy, think about news articles.  Everyone wants "today's news", so those few rows stay in cache.  The occasional request for last-month's news takes a little longer.

Bigger picture...  Let's say your entire dataset is too big for the buffer pool.  Then the optimization is to **minimize the disk hits**.  If, instead, you have inefficient table scans (due to lack of appropriate indexes), things get bumped out of cache "too fast".

If you want to discuss php webpage performance further, give us some clues of dataset size, RAM size, types of queries, etc.